# How to get value from one component to another page/component without navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-hooks, react-router

I have a `navbar` component in which there is an input search bar. Currently I am taking the value of the search bar and navigate to the `Results` component and access the input value `useParams`.

I have the `let [ result, setResult ] = useState([]);` in my `Results` component because the results can change after the search is entered with buttons on the page. The problem is that I cannot set the initial result while defining the `useState` because I am fetching from an API.

So every time I render, I first get an empty array and failed promise, after which I get the desired one. How to fix this? I need the search bar to be in the navbar.

This is the code. New to React.

```
const Navbar = () => {

    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            let value = event.target.value;
            navigate(`/results/${value}`); 
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <nav className='navigation'>
            <div className='left-slot'>
                <button>runtime</button>
            </div>

            <div className="middle-slot">
                <input className="after" 
                placeholder="get runtimes" onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}>
                </input>
            </div>

            <div className='right-slot'>
                <button>How It Works</button>
                <button>Coming Soon</button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}
```

```
const Results = () => {

    let { value } = useParams();
    let [ result, setResult ] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchArrayByPage(value, page, option).then(res => setResult(res))
    }, [value])

    console.log(value);
    console.log(result);
    
    return (<div></div>)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why your code does not work, so I'll provide three options.

**Option 1** - If your problem is `value` is undefined.

Change your `useEffect` in `Results` to this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchArrayByPage(value && value.length ? value : '', page, option).then(res => setResult(res))
}, [value]);
```

**Option 2** - If you need to pass props and `Navbar` and `Results` are not on separate routes.

Just pass `value` as [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) from `Navbar` to `Results`.

**Option 3** - Passing components without props.

Use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). This enables you to share data across components without needing to manually pass props down from parent to child.

1. Initialize variables in context.

- Create separate file containing context.

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

const NavbarContext = createContext(null);

export default NavbarContext;
```

- Import said context to `App.js` or `App.tsx` if you're using Typescript.
- Declare variables and store them in an object for later reference.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
...

const variables = {
    value,
    setValue,
    ...,
};
```

- Wrap with Provider. Pass context variables to the Provider, enabling components to consume `variables`.

```
return (
  <NavbarContext.Provider value={variables}>
    ...
  </NavbarContext.Provider>
);
```

2. Import and use all your variables in `Navbar` and `Results`.

```
const { value, setValue, ... } = useContext(NavbarContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

try a wrapping function for fetching and setting.
i would suggest something like this:

```
async function handleResults(){
    const res = await fetchArrayByPage(value, page, option)
    setResult(res)
}
```

then you can call it inside useEffect